# Get FILL attribute from PATH in SVG by jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg, path, fill

When I click on the SVG, I want to get list of all PATHs from this SVG. And then get FILL from every PATH. But it seems, that jquery doues not know attributte FILL.

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/0q52s2c4/)

HTML

```
<div id="element1" style="width:250px; height:250px; padding:0px; background-color:#ffd;">
<svg style="width:100%; height:100%; " version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="340.156px" height="340.152px" viewBox="0 0 340.156 340.152" enable-background="new 0 0 340.156 340.152"
     xml:space="preserve">
<path id="path_1" fill="#74C750" d="M340.156,170.078c0,93.926-76.146,170.074-170.077,170.074C76.146,340.152,0,264.004,0,170.078
    C0,76.146,76.147,0,170.079,0C264.011,0,340.156,76.146,340.156,170.078z"/>
<path id="path_2" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M54.432,147.366c-12.547,0-22.712,10.166-22.712,22.712c0,12.54,10.165,22.705,22.712,22.705
    c12.54,0,22.705-10.165,22.705-22.705C77.137,157.532,66.972,147.366,54.432,147.366z M216.56,250.57
    c-10.86,6.273-14.585,20.153-8.312,31.008c6.266,10.861,20.146,14.584,31.007,8.313c10.86-6.268,14.584-20.146,8.312-31.01
    C241.3,248.027,227.412,244.304,216.56,250.57z M103.754,170.078c0-22.438,11.146-42.265,28.201-54.27l-16.602-27.807
    c-19.867,13.28-34.648,33.573-40.792,57.342c7.168,5.849,11.756,14.753,11.756,24.732c0,9.977-4.588,18.879-11.756,24.729
    c6.135,23.772,20.917,44.066,40.792,57.348l16.602-27.813C114.901,212.344,103.754,192.519,103.754,170.078z M170.079,103.746
    c34.649,0,63.078,26.567,66.063,60.448l32.355-0.479c-1.593-25.013-12.52-47.468-29.31-63.979
    c-8.635,3.262-18.606,2.763-27.228-2.206c-8.635-4.983-14.049-13.389-15.528-22.514c-8.393-2.316-17.225-3.584-26.354-3.584
    c-15.697,0-30.538,3.687-43.716,10.209l15.777,28.272C150.628,105.966,160.097,103.746,170.079,103.746z M170.079,236.403
    c-9.982,0-19.451-2.221-27.938-6.17l-15.778,28.271c13.178,6.53,28.019,10.22,43.717,10.22c9.131,0,17.963-1.271,26.354-3.594
    c1.479-9.125,6.896-17.521,15.528-22.515c8.626-4.977,18.593-5.467,27.228-2.205c16.79-16.512,27.717-38.967,29.31-63.979
    l-32.364-0.479C233.157,209.845,204.731,236.403,170.079,236.403z M216.551,89.572c10.861,6.272,24.742,2.557,31.009-8.304
    c6.272-10.861,2.559-24.742-8.305-31.018c-10.86-6.266-24.74-2.543-31.017,8.318C201.975,69.425,205.698,83.306,216.551,89.572z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#element1").click(function () {
    $('#element1').children('svg').children('path').each(function () {
        alert(this.attr('fill'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is, that jQuery's `each()`-callback gets the reference to the DOM element and not the respective jQuery object.

So this works for me:

```
$('#element1').children('svg').children('path').each(function () {
    alert( $(this).attr('fill') );
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sirko/0q52s2c4/1/)